# Silverlight / Moonlight / WPF for cross-platform GUI's?

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, user-interface, mono

I need to write a cross platform GUI in F# and it doesn't seem that I have too many choices. I have two questions.

1.) Silverlight is a subset of WPF and is also runnable as a desktop app, which would probably suffice for my needs. But I always had to install the silverlight runtime for any browser based silverlight application. Does this also apply for desktop apps, or does it suffice to have the .NET/Mono installed?

2.) I just read that it is possible to run WPF inside a browser, does this mean I could use WPF for cross-platform GUI's?

Answer (score 4):

XAML based technologies are Windows only.

Moonlight is discountinued and not supported, thus not really recommendable for any new projects.

XBAP (Browser-hosted WPF) is still WPF. It requires the .Net Framework and is Windows only.
It is also not recommended due to the fact that you gain literally *nothing* by using it. Use a pure WPF GUI with it's own Window instead of using Internet Explorer as a Window.

If you need 100% cross-platform and are willing to sacrifice User Experience quality and general code maintainability, create a Web Application using ASP.Net, which delivers HTML content to the client (browser).

if you need a native, high quality User Experience in all devices, then:

- Put your Business Logic in Portable Class Library.
- Create separate client applications which all reference the shared business logic:

  - for Windows Desktop, use WPF.
  - for Windows Metro, use WinRT XAML.
  - for Android and iOS, use Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS respectively.